# Accessing parent through child

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Basically, I have this function. After fgets I want the parent to make the child stop by changing its play variable to 0. How would I do that?

```
    void readQuestion(char * question) {
      int play = 1;
      char inputline[256];
      int s;
      char * holder;
      int p = fork();
      if (p == 0) {
        while(play) {
          holder = strsep(&question," ");
          if(holder) {
        printf("%s\n",holder);
        sleep(1);
          }
          else{
        play = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        fgets(inputline,256,stdin);
        printf("%s",inputline);
        kill();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You will have to find a way to share data between the processes, something `fork()` can't do by itself. You could use shared memory per example, signals, or just go for multi-threading.

Comment: You think I can just kill the child process through the parent? If so, what would be the code for that?

Comment: Once you `fork()` you have two independent processes, they can't interact without some form of IPC such as a pipe.

Comment: @AhsanQureshi: You could always configure a signal handler in the child process and send a signal from the parent. Just killing the child doesn't seem very clean. It also is a perfect occasion for you to learn about threading, or at the very least, signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you want to take one of two approaches...

1. Send a message using a message API like [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) or [socket(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)
2. If you really want to tweak the child's memory you don't want [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) but [a thread library.](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Answer (score 0):

You probablly don't want to fork, but create a thread instead.  Fork is creating a new process,  so you will have two processes each with their own copy of the "play" variable

see...
http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/